# Selecting non-group field from query with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table `tbl` with three columns:

```
id | fk | dateof
 1 |  1 | 2012-01-01
 2 |  1 | 2012-01-02
 3 |  2 | 2012-02-01
 4 |  2 | 2012-03-01
 5 |  3 | 2012-04-01
```

`id` is the ID of the row, `fk` is a foreign key to another table and `dateof` is a date column.

What I want is to get the `id` where the `dateof` is the latest grouped by `fk`. What I've tried:

```
SELECT id, MAX(dateof) FROM tbl GROUP BY fk
```

But I get results like this:

```
1 | 2012-01-02
3 | 2012-03-01
5 | 2012-04-01
```

When I want:

```
2 | 2012-01-02
4 | 2012-03-01
5 | 2012-04-01
```

How can I query and get the results I'm looking for? MySQL server if it matters. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would do

```
SELECT id, tbl.dateof dateof
FROM tbl 
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT fk, MAX(dateof) dateof 
  FROM tbl 
  GROUP BY fk) temp
ON tbl.fk = temp.fk AND tbl.dateof = temp.dateof
```

Gordon's answer is correct and less code, but I prefer creating a temp table. It's more clear to other developers what I'm doing.

Comment: If you switch the join to proper ANSI join syntax, I'll upvote you.

Comment: sorry, I've always been an old school join guy. Hard to break that habit.

Comment: +1 . . . I'm trying to make this one little change in the world (pushing ANSI join syntax ;).

Comment: It's definitely the right way and it's more clear what you're trying to do, so I kind of contradicted my answer doing that :)

Comment: Winner, though with one slight change. dateof is ambiguous according to MySQL, so I put tbl.dateof in the field list. Thanks.

Comment: And one more thing.  The query uses a subquery, which is sometimes referred to as a "derived table".  It does *not* create a temporary table.  That has a specific meaning, referring to tables created with a name that can be shared among multiple queries, generally in a temporary data storage location.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select tbl.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fk order by dateof desc) as seqnum
      from tbl
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

This assumes that you are using a reasonable database that has window functions.  You don't specify the database in your question.

Comment: He's using MySQL - he specified that at the bottom, but didn't tag it

Comment: I'm new here, wasn't sure if MySQL and SQL were too synonymous. I tried this query though, get 0 results. There are a few problems with it as written, such as the first SELECT tbl.*, should be SELECT t.*, no?

Comment: @dlp . . . This query will not work in MySQL.  Matt's solution is the right one for that database.  All other major databases, though, support `row_number()`.